# How to add event listener to many items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
var input = document.getElementById('thumbimg');
            input.addEventListener('change', function() {  $("input.imgcheck").attr("disabled", ""); }, false);
```

I use this code to enable the submit button when the user selects a file to upload.
But what If I want to add more than an upload field? I need to know how to enable the submit button only if all the upload fields are filled. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

[@Simeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419352/simeon) made an important comment and he is right. To solve this problem, you can inspect the value of each field and see whether it is empty or not:

```
var $fields = $('.thumbimg'),
    $submit = $("input.imgcheck"),
     numRequiredFields = $fields.length; // or 3 as per your comment (somewhere)

function runOnChange() {
    var $filledFields = $fields.filter(function(){
        return $(this).val() !== "";
    });
    if($filledFields.length >= numRequiredFields)
        // all fields changed
        // run logic here
        $submit.attr("disabled", "");
    }
    else {
        $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

$fields.change(runOnChange);
```

I hoped to avoid inspecting every field on each change, but it seems this is unavoidable.

---

**Original answer:**

You would have to keep track of which fields have changed. If you have more than one file upload field, you have to use classes, not IDs:

```
var numFields = $('.thumbimg').length,
    changedFields = 0;

function runOnChange() {
    changedFields++;
    if(changedFields >= numFields) {
        // all fields changed
        // run logic here
        $("input.imgcheck").attr("disabled", "");
    }
}

$('.thumbimg').change(runOnChange);
```

Also, if you use jQuery anyway, then be consistent and use it throughout the script. Especially don't use `addEventListener`, which does not work in IE8 and below. jQuery is there to abstract from this browser differences.

Comment: If the user changes a file selection several times this will produce an incorrect result, as the `change` event is run every time the file is changed

Answer (score 4):

On one hand, you can use a more generic selector. For instance :

```
$(".mytest").change(function() { $(this).attr("disabled", ""); } ;
```

will apply the event to every element which contains the class `mytest`.

On the other hand, you can use the [delegate function](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). For instance :

```
$("#myContainer").delegate(".mytest", "change", function(){ $(this).attr("disabled", ""); });
```

will apply the event to every element which contains the class `mytest` but belongs to the main container whose id is `myContainer`.

[EDIT] (changed the code above)
To check if your inputs are filled, you can use this code (should work even if not tested right here) using the [name selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) :

```
if ($('input[disabled!=""]').length !== 0) {
   // submit
}
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: Hello max, thanks for your reply. However this code enables makes the functions run if any of the fields changed, however I want to enable it only if ALL of the fields have changed.

Comment: Just check the value on all the file inputs on each change event. If none of them are empty, then enable the submit button.

Comment: @Mohamed Said: i edited my answer to fit better your question

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
$('input').change(function() {

});
```

to bind the function to the [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event for all `<input>` elements. Then add any checks to the function body and enable the `<input type="submit"/>` if the validation passes.

There are some jQuery plugins available that you might be able to use - [jQueryFormValidtor](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryFormValidtor) (for example) and [jQuery Form Validation Plugins](http://www.techtricky.com/jquery-form-validation-plugins/) look like a good place to start.

Comment: I'm already using a jquery validator, however I'm trying to force the user to upload three images before being able to submit the form, that's why I'm disabling the submit button.

Is there and AND condition in jquery? like $('input and input2').change(function( ...

so that the function does't run unless the three inputs are changed ?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer *<strike>does</strike>* **did** not work correctly. The submit button would be enabled if the user changes file/image in the first file field a number of times.

Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zP5b/5/), which checks that each input has a value. Code:

```
var fileInputs = $('input[type=file]');
var submitBtn = $('input[type=submit]');
fileInputs.change(function() {
    if(fileInputs.filter('[value=""]').length == 0)
        submitBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        submitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```